# How to Redirect back to my website after transaction ends on Razorpay . Note: if "redirect=true" is passed as an option

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, payment-gateway, razorpay

Firstly I am using React and NodeJs for this integration.

I know it's possible to redirect back to the website by using *location.href* in the handler function.

But what if we are using **redirect=true** as an options.

It's also mentioned that we can pass the *callback_url* to the options object. This will make razorpay to redirect to this URL after a successful transaction but this is going to be a **POST** request. So, we cannot give the URL of our website in here.

example:

```
const options = {
  key: "razorpay_key",
  currency: data.currency,
  amount: data.amount.toString(),
  order_id: data.id,
  handler: function (response) {
    alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
    alert(response.razorpay_order_id);
    alert(response.razorpay_signature);
  },
  prefill: {
    name,
    email: "abcd@xyz.com",
    contact: "9999999999",
    method: "netbanking",
  },
  redirect: true, // this redirects to the bank page from my website without opening a new window
  callback_url: "not sure what to do with it",
};
```

Is there any way I can get back to the cart/website page with these parameters in params (razorpay_payment_id, razorpay_order_id, razorpay_signature) after completion of the transaction.

here you can check all the parameters for checkout options: https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/server-integration/nodejs/payment-gateway/build-integration/#checkout-options

Razorpay web checkout docs link: https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payment-gateway/web-integration/standard/

Comment: Can you link us to the API docs? (and make sure they're publicly accessible?)

Comment: Sure, I've added the doc links in the question.

Comment: The POST request is made to your server to confirm the payment. The `callback_url` on the other hand is the URL the razorpay website will redirect to after the payment, just like it says in the docs. This is where you put your own website url (specifically the url of the page you want to go back to after the payment)

Comment: @ChrisG I even tried putting my webpage url as `callback_url`, but then got 404 in network tab as it was a **POST** req in the browser. [link](https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payment-gateway/callback-url/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I found a way to do the same.
As I am using SSR, I created a POST route on my server and simply redirected from there to my webpage.

like,

```
app.post('/verification', asyncHandler((req, res) => {res.redirect(301, `webpage_url?query_param=${req.body.razorpay_payment_id}`}))
```

so, checkout options object looks like below

```
const options = {
    ... // existing options
    redirect: true,
    callback_url: "server_address/verification",
};
```

Hope it helps someone out facing the same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have another db which stores all the value for your order.

So, Your callback_url will be -

Api to the database + unique order_id to provide you with details of order.

```
var options = {
  ... // existing options
  callback_url: 'https://localhost:3000/cart'+order_id,
  redirect: true
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question "callback_url" should accept POST method, so how can we redirect it to our webpage which should be a GET URL.  You can checkout this for more information about callback_url 
https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payment-gateway/callback-url/

Comment: @MayankGangwar I think the redirect will only work in one case. As API docs says "
 `redirect- Determines whether to post a response to the event handler post-payment completion or redirect to Callback URL. callback_url must be passed while using this parameter. Possible values:

true: Customer is redirected to the specified callback URL in case of payment failure.
false (default): Customer is shown the Checkout popup to retry the payment.
`
"

Comment: But then without using `redirect=true` Razorpay opens up the bank's page in a new separate window which was the main reason I went for this parameter. Let me know if there is some other way to achieve the same without using a redirect.